# retrive the checkin comment using REST in sharepoint?

Tags: javascript, rest, sharepoint

i have tried to update,checkout,checkin AND retrive the checkin comment but im getting value does not fall within the range error? anything i have missed ?

```js
               var getfileurl = document.getElementById("getfileurl").value;
        //i have entered the path like /lib/folder/test.docx
alert(getfileurl);
var executor;



// Initialize the RequestExecutor with the app web URL.

executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);

executor.executeAsync({

url: appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('" + getfileurl + "')/CheckInComment?@target='" + hostweburl + "'",

method: "GET",

headers: {

"Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"

},

success: SuccessHandler,

error: ErrorHandler

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The error:

> Value does not fall within the expected range

occurs since `serverRelativeUrl` parameter for [SP.Web.getFileByServerRelativeUrl Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246729.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) should be specified *as server-relative URL for the file*, for example:

```
/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/site/web/library/filename')
```

**Solution**

Specify file url in the following format:

```
/site/hostweb/library/filename
```

for example:

```
var fileurl = _spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl + "/documents/filename";
```